# Patching 19c including MRPs

Tags: oracle, patching

If I have 19.19 patch and latest MRP and I want to patch up to 19.22 do I need to manually remove the MRPs or are they going to be removed by the opatch ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you don't have to do nothing with MRPs. Oracle says: Q18: When 19.21 DB RU is being applied , will opatch report a conflict if (19.20 DB RU + MRP 1 + MRP 2+MRP 3) are applied? What sort of conflict – Subset /Superset? A18: A: No. There will not be a conflict reported as the next RU will act as a superset of the prior 3 MRPs installed.